Optimizing $\alpha$ parameter in $\alpha$-shape calculations: to what precision?
I am calculating alpha shapes for a large amount of 3D point clouds (each of ca 2000 pts). They are fairly homogeneous and has a sphere-like topology while concave, but of course contain some finer structure as well, which I want to capture, hence using alpha shape.
I am using the alphashape Python package, which uses a bisection method to narrow down the lower (L) and upper (U) bounds on $\alpha$ ($\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is the radius of the circumcircles used to create the alpha shape). It stops either when maximum iterations is reached (returns $\alpha=0$ which just yields a convex hull) or when $|L-U|<\delta$ in which case it returns $U$. For many cases this works fine, but for many the process gets into a prolonged iteration (hours) that max out even for very large max_iter. This is due to the very high precision that optimizealpha.py uses: $\delta=$np.finfo(float).eps * 2, which is fixed and they don't give as an optional parameter.
I've speed this up by changing the source code to include a precision parameter, and use something on the order of $d_{min}*10^{-6}$, where $d_{min}\approx 0.03$ is the smallest point-wise distance in my data ($d_{max}\approx 1.8$). But now I'm unsure how wise this is:
TL;DR Question:
Is there a robust or at least somewhat reasonable way I can pick a precision value for the bisection method optimizing the $\alpha$ parameter (preferably much larger than np.eps) based on some metric of my data, like pairwise distances etc.?
(or is this question better suited elsewhere?)
